# While changing nameservers,whole website goes down in aws and hostinger as dns provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, cloud, cross-domain

The issue is we have hosted our site on AWS
And there is a service called route 53 for creating hosted zones and so we have used route 53 and hostinger which is nothing but the DNS provider.

So at the email domain section is not working
Due to AWS service which we had used for web hosting
It says the DNS servers are not pointing towards hostinger DNS server.

[image: Error image]

Main issue is if we change the nameservers the whole website will go down.
We can't change the nameservers
There should be a middle way to deal with this.

Comment: It's very unclear what the issue is.  Based on the screen shot it looks like hostinger requires you to have your DNS with them.  I'd undo everything until you understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i hhighly apologise for you not reverting back.The problemv has been solved and yes you are correct.